# Upgraded my Ubuntu 22.03.4 LTS system from a 1.0TB Hard Disk to a 2.0 TB SSD, Windows 10 in partition 1 works, but I can't access Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have cloned the new SSD using Acronis, I can boot Windows with an old "GRUB" disk, but I cannot get into Ubuntu to edit the settings. The Command Line is not accessible. I downloaded the Disk Image File, which shows in Properties as 4.69 GB (5,037,662,208 bytes), the Image File is 4,919,592 bytes, but Windows says the file will not fit on the disk (a new DVD) My "GRUB Disk is original Grub, and won't access the later versions of Ubuntu because they are GRUB 2. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu does not fit on DVDs anymore, you have to use a flash drive. You can download one of the flavors which are smaller & better suited for older systems. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  I use Kubuntu and 22.04.3 is 4GB.

Comment: I have now uploaded and installed Ubuntu 23.10, as the Legacy file does fit on a DVD. It runs ok, however I now cannot access the Windows 10 partition, I had installed Grub2Win on the Windows "C" Drive, which let me boot to Ubuntu but now all that is inaccessible, my original idea was to try 23.10 and if I had issues, go back to 23.04 LTS version. This seems to be a common problem? Any ideas please

Comment: If Windows 10, it should be UEFI. Did you install in UEFI boot mode? Both systems must be in same boot mode for grub to be able to also boot Windows. Windows also must have fast startup off which sets a hibernation flag and bitlocker off. Otherwise os-prober cannot see drive. If older system with 4GB or less of RAM lightweight flavor will be better and those fit on DVDs. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
I use Kubuntu and its ISO is 4.0 GiB.